# Prevent Users from Replying to Email on a Case unless you're the Case Owner?

Tags: email, case, ownership

Is there a way to prevent a user from replying to an email on a Case record, or perhaps not seeing the email related list, if they're not the case owner?

(to force them to take case ownership before they can reply)

Thank you!

Comment: put your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: I have not tried any code.  I'm not sure which approach to even take.  I'm currently experimenting with changing Record Types (and thus Page Layouts) based on whether a case owner is a Queue or User.  (and making the Page Layout for Queues to hide all the pertinent details, including the Email related list.)

Comment: If user has a EDIT permission he can able to send email. So either give the user to read-only access to the case, other than owner. Write to trigger to handle this functionality

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this.

**First,** I created two Record Types for Cases. One called "Hidden Details", and the other "Full Details".

**Second,** I created two different Layouts for Cases. One Layout has a bunch of the information removed, including the Emails related list; and the other layout is our full case layout.

**Third,** I assigned the layouts to their respective Record Types.

**Fourth,** I created a Process in Process builder, that for every time a record is created or edited, if the owner is a Queue, the Record Type becomes "Hidden Details" and if the owner is ever a User, the Record Type becomes "Full Details" .. this is done using RecordTypeID field.

**NOTE 1:** To be able to tell whether the Case Owner is a Queue or User, this formula should be used: `LEFT([Case].OwnerId,3) = "00G"` to check if owner is a Queue and `LEFT([Case].OwnerId,3) = "005"` to check if the owner is a User.  Because the ID of Queues always begins with 00G and the ID of regular users always begins with 005.

**NOTE 2:** To get Record Type IDs, open up the Record Type such as when you go to edit it, and look for the ID string in the website URL.

**NOTE 3:** Do note that you cannot have one "Hidden Details" Record Type and your Master record type (the record type you get if you don't use Record Types), and that you will need to create a Record Type for your new default record type, ie: my "Full Details" Record Type.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same issue, was able to resolve it with the validation rule on email message object this is how my look like:
AND
(  CONTAINS(Parent.RecordType.Name, 'Message'),
Incoming = FALSE,
$Profile.Name != 'SCB Admin',
$UserRole.Name != 'FI Team Lead',
Parent.OwnerId !=  $User.Id
)